# Different CSS based on width

Tags: html, css

I have a website that uses "card" views. When viewed on a desktop I set the CSS for the card as such:

```
width: 75%
margin: auto
```

I did this so the "card" would not take up the entire width which looks nicer on the desktop:

[image]

But what I am trying to figure out is how to take the width and margins auto off when the screen sizes changes to a mobile smaller screen. I want the card to be width 100% when in mobile view for obvious reasons. How can I change the CSS based on width of the window?

Comment: Use media query man. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Use Media Queries: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: They are easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a standard bootstrap mediaqueries.make sure you put this meta tag on head

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">




/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}



/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```